# Implement loop in the SQL query, not in PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

Is it possible to write the loop in the SQL query?
Or is it only possible in PHP? (write loop in php, where I execute the query at every iteration)

Example:

Is it possible for a query, to contain a loop like this:

```
LOOP(50) { UPDATE Table SET X=X+1 }
```

Or I have to write it in php, and call the single query at every iteration?

Comment: You could eleborate a litle more in your question.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please refer to mysql documentation / tutorials to learn more on the topic:  https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6289.simple-loops

Comment: You can execute statements in a MySQL stored procedure. You can't do loops in ordinary SQL queries.

Comment: What rows do you want to update and to what value?

Comment: Why don't you just do `SET X = X + 50`?

Comment: Technically, you can make a loop with SQL but it is better to avoid that. From your question I can guess that you are more PHP person and not quite familiar with SQL. SQL is not designed to work that way because  it is using "set based logic". Read some basic book about SQL before you continue. I'm afraid you are headed in wrong direction.

Comment: I want to fill up a table with locations, on a 150x150 map. Last time I used a loop in PHP, which randomly generated a tile for that location, and if everything went correct all the 22500 tiles were created. But now I want to do it smarter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table that contains sequential numbers. Then you can use a `JOIN` with this table to make the query loop.

```
UPDATE Table 
CROSS JOIN Numbers AS n
SET X = X + 1
WHERE n.number BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure that accepts a parameter for the number of loops.
MSSQL syntax:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 5;
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @x INT = 0;

WHILE @i < @cnt
BEGIN
 SET @x = @x + 2;
 SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

MySql syntax:

```
WHILE i < cnt DO
...
END WHILE
```